# Setting default values for specific days

Tags: javascript

I am using the script from http://jsfiddle.net/urQc4/ on my site to show/edit store hours. The script works fine but I would like to add some lines in the JavaScript to set some default values for specific days/times.

When I add this to line 47 of the JavaScript it works

```
$('#Sunday .from').val(["12"]);
```

But when i try to add code to set the hours, minutes and am/pm it doesn't work

```
$('#Sunday .from').val(["12"]);
$('#Sunday .from').val([":30"]);
$('#Sunday .from').val(["PM"]);
```

If anyone can help me out I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it would be your `selectors` that is not right.

You have to be more specific and select the right dropdown.

*I got this snippet to work:*

```
$('#Sunday .from.hour').val(["12"]);
$('#Sunday .from.min').val([":30"]);
$('#Sunday .from.ampm').val(["PM"]);
```

The `.from.hour` insures that the element have both `from` and `hour` css class.